# Nginx gzip_types - a redundant directive in some cases?

Tags: nginx

Please see this Nginx directive:

```
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

Should we say that Nginx `gzip_types` might be a redundant directive in case you want everything to be gzipped?

For example, if I want everything whatsoever to be gzipped, should I take it down? If so, it might do User Experience damage serve everything gzipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want everything to be gzipped, you should use *special value* called `*`.

```
gzip_types *;
```

As always, there is no proper and general answer for question: *What should be compressed?* What is gzipped and when, might depend on application logic.

References:

- [ngx_http_gzip_module | Nginx Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html)